# is there any way to show input value to an object in alert box?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm trying to show some input values in alert box. Basically i want to do a basic login ui. When somebody click on login, i want to pop an alert box with values from inputs. I found out that this was verry easy, just adding .value to that element. But i want to have another button with signup, and when somebody press on the button i want to show in an alert box something like {{email: , characterNumber:},{pass: , characterNumber:}}.

My code looks like this

`<div class="login-container">
      <mwc-textfield id="emailText" type="email" class="email-input" label="email" helper="Insert email">
      </mwc-textfield>`

```
  <mwc-textfield id="passwordText" type="password" class="password-input" label="password" helper="Insert password">
  </mwc-textfield>
  <br />

  <mwc-button id="logIn" label="Log in"> </mwc-button>
  <mwc-button id="signUp" label="Sign up"> </mwc-button>
</div>
```

And the js code

```
const login = document.querySelector("#logIn");
const signUp = document.querySelector("#signUp");
const textfield = document.querySelector('#emailText');
const emailVal = document.querySelector('#emailText').value;
const passVal = document.querySelector('#passwordText').value;

login.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("Your email adress: " + emailText.value + '\n' + "Your password: " + passwordText.value);
});

signUp.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert(emailText.value);
});


let email = {
  adress: emailText.value,
  pass: passwordText.value,
}
```

i tried to alert the email value but the alert box was empty

but when i click on the button its shows me just the adress, without email or password value from the input.

I'm trying to explain as good as i can, but english is not my native language, i hope someboy can help me

Comment: can you share the whole code ?

Comment: Sure, i edited my post with the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you can not have an Alert Box with multiple input fields, you can then have multiple alert box for different fields. like the following:

```js
let user = prompt('user');
let password = prompt('password');
const confirmText = `user: ${user} with the password: ${password}`
let confirmResult = confirm(confirmText);
console.log("confirmation status:", confirmResult);
```

the other solution would be to use a dialog, modal or popup, based on the ui library that you are using.